# Java Guice: Run time dependency re-wiring

Tags: java, guice

I have several classes StrategyAlpha, StrategyBeta, StrategyOmega that inherit from the Strategy class.

I would like to select the proper child Strategy depending on property of inputs using guice, the dependency injection framework.

Is wiring the dependencies at runtime a bad idea?
How can use Guice to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to bind something like a StrategyProvider which, given inputs, returns the appropriate strategy.

You could always create a provider - something like:

@Inject
StrategyProvider(@Named("alpha") Strategy alpha, @Named("beta") Strategy beta...) {
     this.alpha = alpha;
     this.beta = beta;
}

Strategy get(Parameter a, parameter b) {
 if (a > 3 && b < 10) {
   return beta;
 } else {
   return alpha;
 }
}

What the params are, and why would determine whether this makes sense, more than likely.

Comment: http://www.javabeat.net/articles/29-introduction-to-google-guice-5.html gives a detailled example on how to use Guice Providers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you need is a factory to instantiate appropriate object depending on a set of properties.

You can implement the factory using factory design pattern - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: In Guice, what you call factories are called Suppliers  http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Supplier.html or Providers http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/Provider.html